# my jquery plugin and accessing a global seems inappropriate. Better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a previous question and I feel I wasn't succinct enough. So , here is my code example and my accessing of a global. I feel this is bad form, but I can't find another way to do this given my plugin format.

I believe I could apply my functions to a method var and then instantiate that via the plugin in call, but so far - my plugin isn't set up like that and think that might be more work. But I'd like to hear from more experienced jQuery plugin creators.

Usage:
Data is front loaded. As dynamic content is created. I gobbled up some pertinent information pertaining to it, bundle it up, send an ajax call - then update the view. The thing is. My plugin could be called numerous times on a page. But the thing is I need to grab some data objects PRIOR to calling my plugin so I then can operate on them and determine "what I need to update". So that is my issue. I need to get some data outside of the plugin. THEN i need to pass it in. Is this considered "appropriate".

My hope was I could funnel the data into a method of the plugin and then when I call it I have the data to make some display choices.

```
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
Object.create = function( obj ) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = obj;
    return new F();
};
}
// this is the global that I push each reiteration of data into.
var perLineDataArray = [];
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {
var Sustainability = {
    _init: function( options, elem ) {
        var self = this;
        self.elem = elem;
        self.$elem = $( elem );
        /* plugin call has all the data I need, I pass it in here */
        self.perLineData = groupedperLineData;
        self.url = 'path_to_url/sustainability';
        self.options = $.extend( {}, $.fn.querysustainability.options, options );
        self._extractUrlData();
        self._cleanup();

    },
            _extractUrlData: function(){
               // this is where I would go thru each of the data objects and 
               // determine WHAT in the view needs updating based on some critera.
            },
    _getsustain: function()
            {
              var self = this;
              $.ajax({
                       // my ajax call data
                            success: function(data){
                                this._buildUpdate(data);
                            }
                  });
            },
    _buildDispaly: function( results ) {
        var self = this;
        self.sustainability = $.map( results, function( obj, i) {
            return $( self.options.wrapDisplay ).append ( obj.text )[0];
        });
    },
            _cleanup: function(){
               // clean out global array for next funneling of grouped up data
               perLineDataArray = [];
            },
    _showMessage: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.$elem[ self.options.transition ]( 500, function() {
             $(this).html( self.sustainability )[ self.options.transition ]( 500 );
        });

    },
};
$.fn.querysustainability = function( options, method ) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var sustainability = Object.create( sustainability );
        sustainability._init( options, this );
        $.data( this, 'querysustainability', sustainability );
    });
};

$.fn.querysustainability.options = {
    display: '<span></span>',
    usedClass : 'uniqueclass',
    transition: 'fadeToggle'
};


 })( jQuery, window, document );
```

I haven't worked out all the code yet, but that is the jist.. so here is how i would push the data into the global.

```
 //Some reiteration of building of HTML dom element displays.
 perLineDataArray.push(some_per_iteration_obj);
```

Then, when the display is build and I have all the objects I need - THEN I call the plugin.

```
    jQuery('#planets').querysustainability({
        groupedperLineData: perLineDataArray
     });
```

Or I could add the global here:

```
    $.fn.querysustainability.options = {
    display: '<span></span>',
    usedClass : 'uniqueclass',
    transition: 'fadeToggle',
    groupedperLineData: perLineDataArray
};
```

My gut is telling me I want the plugin to encapsulate everything but then another part of me feels I need to pass in what I need to operate on and now have my plugin retrieve it.

So, is there a way to call a sub-method of the plugin, store up the data set and then when I call the plugin, it has that data ready or ?

your thoughts? And if how do you feel I should solve this, code wise?

Comment: Mu suggestion would be to create in "init" function that must be called before "use" of plugin rather than before the plugin is called, but then i havn't completely read your work yet. But just my first thought.

Comment: that is probably what I could do - but how do I do that ? Is the only way via creating a "methods" var and then instantiating them? I've seen those questions answered.. but curious if my implementation could make it work OR if using a global is ok?

Comment: Just a word of advice, globals are almost never ok in that a plugin needs to be self-sustained. In other words, I need to be able to use it with jQuery on any platform. I would suggest adding your array inside your plugin's namespace or possibly even look at using jQuery's .data() abilities. I have a basic plugin layout, i will try and find it tommorow and post it for you or email it to ya or something. It's basically a template and you just use it as your layout scheme for your plugin. Its really easy to follow and I've used it over and over again to make dozens of plugins for companies.

Comment: oh, that would be great if you could. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey SpYK - I've done some research and I think I understand your usage of data and do you think that would be appropriate? I can Tie in some dataObj onto each of my reiterated elements. THEN when I call the plugin - I can then scoops up all the data-attributes, run thru THAT data and make some choices.. But I'd like to see what you have for a template plugin, as I am guessing mine is sorta off-kilter.

Comment: No problem, i'll post the template as an answer this evening when i get back home (finally!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as aforementioned in comments, the following is my most basic of jQuery plugin layout templates. From it you can design pretty much any jQuery plugin you want and have a ton of versatility. It's pretty self explanatory. Just look it over and if it helps, great, if not let me know and I'll remove it as an answer.

```
/*  Example Plug-in Setup   */
(function($) {
    if (!$.myExample) { // your plugin namespace
        $.extend({
            myExample: function(elm, command, args) {
                return elm.each(function(index){
                    // do work to each element as its passed through
                    // be sure to use something like
                    //      return elm.each(function(e) { dor work });
                    // as your final statement in order to maintain "chainability"
                });
            }
        });
        $.fn.extend({
            myExample: function(command) {
                return $.myExample($(this), command, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            }
        });
        $.myExample.props = {
            key1: "value",
            key2: "value"
        };
        $.myExample.methods = {
            key1: function(param) {

            },
            key2: function(param) {

            }
        };
        $.myExample.init = function(param) {
            var key = "value",
                key2 = {
                    subKey: "value"
                };
                /*
                /  run any number of initializing functions here
                /  I prefer to make my param a value that can be a
                /   string with a possible object
                /    the string for holding a base configuration
                /    the object for any change in properties or base values for that config
                */
        };
        $.myExample.defaults = {
            key1: "value",
            key2: {
                prop1: {
                    subKey1: "value",
                    subKey2: "value"
                },
                prop2: {
                    subKey1: "value"
                }
            },
            key3: function(param) {

            }
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```